# How to scrape time-series chart data from poocoin.app with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [token info from poocoin](https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x7606267a4bfff2c5010c92924348c3e4221955f2). All other information is available but I can't scrape time-series data from the chart.

```py
import requests, re 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x7606267a4bfff2c5010c92924348c3e4221955f2'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The new approach would be to reverse engineer the `data` URL parameter:

[image]

When I'll have a solution, I'll update the answer.

---

Previous method:

You can make it work by making a direct request to their API (*I believe*), transform it to JSON via `requests` [`.json()` decoder](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), and grab the data you need the same way you would access a dictionary: `["some_key"]`.

To locate where to send the request: `Dev tools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR -> find name and click on it` (in this case: *candles-bsc?..*) `-> Preview` (see if response is what you want) `-> Headers -> copy Request URL -> make a request -> optional: add additional request headers if response != 200`.

You can use [Insomnia to test a response](https://insomnia.rest/). Find name under `Fetch/XHR -> right click -> copy as cURL (bash) -> place inside Insomnia -> see the reponse`.

---

In this case, you only need to pass a [`user-agent` to request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) in order to receive a `200` status code, otherwise, it will throw a `403` or `503` status code. Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
}

response = requests.get("URL", headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/How-to-scrape-time-series-chart-data-from-poocoinapp-with-P#main.py):

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
}

params = {
    "to":"2021-11-29T09:15:00.000Z",
    "limit":"321",
    "lpAddress":"0xd8b6A853095c334aD26621A301379Cc3614f9663", 
    "interval":"15m",
    "baseLp":"0x58F876857a02D6762E0101bb5C46A8c1ED44Dc16"
}


response = requests.get("https://api2.poocoin.app/candles-bsc", params=params, headers=headers).json()


# whole response from API call for a particular token (i believe)
# some data needs to be adjusted (open/close price, etc.)
for result in response:
    count = result["count"]
    _time = result["time"]
    open_price = result["open"]
    close_price = result["close"]
    high = result["high"]
    low = result["low"]
    volume = result["volume"]
    base_open = result["baseOpen"]
    base_close = result["baseClose"]
    base_high = result["baseHigh"]
    base_low = result["baseLow"]

    print(f"{count}\n"
          f"{_time}\n"
          f"{open_price}\n"
          f"{close_price}\n"
          f"{high}\n"
          f"{low}\n"
          f"{volume}\n"
          f"{base_open}\n"
          f"{base_close}\n"
          f"{base_high}\n"
          f"{base_low}\n")


# part of the output:
'''
194
2021-11-29T06:00:00.000Z
6.6637177e-13
6.5189422e-13
6.9088173e-13
5.9996067e-13
109146241968737.17
610.0766516756873
611.1764494818917
612.3961994618185
606.7446709385977

1
2021-11-25T16:15:00.000Z
1.7132448e-13
1.7132448e-13
1.7132448e-13
1.7132448e-13
874858231833.1771
643.611707269882
642.5014860521045
644.5105804619558
638.9447353699617

# ...
'''
```

Comment: hi, is there any way we can get such details direct from blockchain ?

Comment: Hi, @ChiragJoshi. Directly from blockchain? Probably yes as cryptocurrency price trackers doing exactly it. You can try to scrape [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/thoreum-v2/) general token info as well as charts data which may be a little easier approach. Poocoin is using TradingVIew API and probably Binance Smart Chain Explorer where the data probably is coming from. The new approach I mentioned is almost done, and probably will be finished soon with a detailed blog post.